# How to write a large number in SQL table with Workbench?

Tags: mysql, datatable, workbench

When I tried to fill in a big number, error. How to add the maximum limit of INT?

```
UPDATE `test`.`number` SET `idNumber` = '36552124313028521236524313028' WHERE (`idNumber` = '365521');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try use a BigInt

If you want a number larger than the largest 64-bit unsigned integer 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 then you will need to store it as a varchar or some other Text form

refer to the  [MySQL data types](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-data-types.aspx) for further info

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the column is to be used. For calculations or auto_increment attribute, numerics should be used. As you say you would like to add a maximum limit, by **ADD** I suppose you would like to define a length value to your liking. However, the whole number types such as small int, int, big int have a **predefined** maximum range , which can not be changed.（MySQL 8.0 users may try the `check option`, which is ignored in previous versions） If you need to define the limit for the whole number, there is a workaround by using decimal(n,0) to make the number always appear as a whole number. 
For identifiers which do not require numerical calculations, `varchar` is generally acknowledged for strings that have a dynamic range, and `char` is more suitable for those having a static length,such as province acronym e.g AZ (Arizona) AR (Arkansas) CA (California). At the first glance of your `idNumber` column, I reckon it's better used for it's string's nature rather than numerics. 
Last but not least. Please **refrain** from using a varchar for string-looking values that are prone to calculations,such as IP ADDRESS. It appears as a string in its dotted format, but deep inside it has an inherent nature of numerics. For instance, IPV4 has a range from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 , which can be treated as a formula of (256 * 256 * 256 * 256) . Thus it is a perfect fit for the unsigned integer type in terms of length and can be calculated when necessary. To display it in its dotted format , use the `inet_ntoa()` function. e.g `select inet_ntoa(3232235777);`